# Using predicates in lambdas with lambda parameters

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, predicate

I'm trying to compare an object against a list of objects to know if this particular object is on the list, however there are some rules

1. I don't want to override any existing methods
2. I don't want to use custom comparators
3. Solution should use already existing predicates

Code below:

```
List<String> PREDEFINED_CODES = Arrays.asList(PredefinedCodes.1, PredefinedCodes.2, PredefinedEventSetupCodes.3, PredefinedEventSetupCodes.4);

private BiPredicate<Event, String> isEventOfCode(){
    return (event, code) -> code.equals(event.getCode());
}

private Predicate<Event> isEvendPredefined(){
    return event -> PREDEFINED_CODES.stream().findAny(code -> isEventOfCode().test(event,code)).isPresent();
}
```

Note: This is simplified version of code to show my problem

Now the problem, I'm having this `code -> isEventOfCode().test(event,code)` in this lambda I can not test values against `isEventOfCode` predicate because `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: '<lambda parameter>', required: 'java.lang.String'` although I know that `PREDEFINED_CODES` is a list of string, therefore `code` is of type `String`

Is there some workaround for calling the `isEventOfCode()` predicate with a parameter from lambda expression? I can not modify type of `isEventOfCode()` since its used in other parts of code.

Comment: But what advantage shall this `BiPredicate<Event, String>` returning method have? If you want to encapsulate the `code.equals(event.getCode())` operation, you can use an ordinary method.

Comment: @Holger this is used in other parts of code to order some conditions and since logic for comparing these two values is in place, there is no point of creating dedicated method, also as stated in question this is simplified version of comparasion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`findAny()` takes no argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny()) - so you typically use it on a stream that has a filter to check if there are any elements left after filtering. In your example, you would use:

```
return event -> PREDEFINED_CODES.stream().filter(code -> isEventOfCode().test(event,code))
                                         .findAny().isPresent();
```

But for your use case, it would make more sense [to use `anyMatch` instead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)):

```
return event -> PREDEFINED_CODES.stream().anyMatch(code -> isEventOfCode().test(event,code));
```

Comment: of course, this is correct answer. I have mixed up findAny() with anyMatch(). Thank you!